# How to call a method from a class in another .jar?

Tags: java, methods, jar

I have .jar-file, called `Plugin.jar` which contains a single class, `plugin.Plugin`, with the method `public ArrayList<String> getList()`.

I am trying to call that method from my main program, which is a completely different NetBeans project.

However, I get a `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: object is not an instance of declaring class` on the last line before the `catch` clause.

The main program (the one that is calling `getList()` in the other .jar) looks like this:

```
public class PluginMain {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            File file = new File("plugins/Plugin.jar");
            URL url = file.toURI().toURL();
            URL[] urls = new URL[]{url};
            ClassLoader cl = new URLClassLoader(urls);

            Class cls = cl.loadClass("plugin.Plugin");
            Method method = cls.getDeclaredMethod("getList");
            ArrayList<String> invoke = (ArrayList<String>) method.invoke(cls);
        } catch (MalformedURLException | ClassNotFoundException | NoSuchMethodException | SecurityException | IllegalAccessException | IllegalArgumentException | InvocationTargetException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(PluginMain.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
}
```

The `plugin.Plugin` class from the `Plugin.jar` looks like this:

```
public class Plugin {

    public Plugin() {
    }

    public ArrayList<String> getList(){
        ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList();
        list.add("String1");
        list.add("String2");
        list.add("String3");
        return list;
    }
}
```

This is my first time attempting anything like this and I'm truly lost, as to what I should do to fix the exception. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Add Plugin.jar in class path. and import that class in main and use it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`Method#invoke(Object, Object...)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Method.html#invoke%28java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.Object...%29) method expects an instance of the class to which the method belongs.

You have a few choices with reflection. If your class has a no-args constructor (as it does), you can use

```
Object instance = cls.newInstance();
```

and then pass that

```
ArrayList<String> invoke = (ArrayList<String>) method.invoke(instance);
```

If your class doesn't have a no-args constructor, you'll need to choose from the available constructors with

```
Constructor[] constructors = cls.getConstructors();
```

---

> I am trying to call that method from my main program, which is a
>   completely different NetBeans project.

Note that as long as the class files are on the class path, you can very much just do

```
Plugin plugin = new Plugin();
...
```

the fact that it's in a different project has nothing to do with how you run a `java` program.

Comment: Thanks a ton. It works perfectly fine now. The Plugin class isn't in the classpath though, so I can't instantiate it normally (new Plugin()). Using the cls.newInstance() method did the trick.